# Do I have to initialize every level of an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm not terribly good with Javascript so I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing this:

```
if (games[level] === undefined) {
    games[level] = {};
    games[level]['pending'] = {};
}

if (!games[level]['pending'].length) {
    return game.create(level);
}
```

In PHP I can just test empty($games[$level]['pending']). Is there a better way of testing for this? Basically all I want to do is create the object if it does not exist.

Comment: You'll always get a `TypeError` when even checking for properties of something that's `undefined`, so you need to. However, I'm not aware of any tips and tricks to make this easier.

Comment: Yeah I found that out the hard way. Just hoping there is some "guru" out there that can make it a bit more elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (games[level] === undefined) {
    games[level] = game.create(level);
}
```

If there is no such level game create should be called to initialize all of the data needed. I don`t see any point of making it an object and then checking for "pending". It will be always empty, because you just created the object.

<strike>If your the second if returns something for `games[level]['pending'].length` you have a big problem with your code. You can`t create an empty object ( games[level]['pending'] = {} ) and find that it **already** has properties.</strike>

In addition:

```
games[level] = {};
// games[level]['pending'] = {}; - bad
games[level].pending = {}; // this way object properties should be used
```

Comment: Basically what I wanted to do is add a new item to the pending (waiting to start games) object. In the code games[level].pending it's possible that it is set already (so undefined wont be triggered) but had no items in it. Hence the .length check.

Answer (score 1):

you can make yourself a function to do that, pass it the games object a a string like "level.pending.id.something.something" and goes on and creates the objects.

```
function makeObj(obj, path) {
    var parts = path.split("."), tmp = obj, name;
    while (parts.length) { 
        name = parts.shift();
        if (typeof tmp[name] === 'undefined') {
              tmp[name] = {};
        }
        tmp = tmp[name];
    }
}

var x = {};
makeObj(x, "this.is.a.test");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
games[level] = games[level] || {pending: {}};

if (!games[level].pending.length) {
    return game.create(level);
}
```